# Response types from web api 2 and how to handle them in Angular 6

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, angular6

I am bit confused how I should send my responses from my web api to an Angular 6 SPA. To begin with I was using BadRequestErrorMessageResult like this

```
[HttpGet()]
public IHttpActionResult Error1()
{
    //... some error
    return BadRequest("Error1");
}
```

But if I had to return a 403 I would go

```
[HttpGet()]
public IHttpActionResult Error2()
{
    //..Error occured..
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Error2"));
}
```

Then I was reading the the guide here on error handling https://angular.io/guide/http and tried something quite similar to the example.

I wanted to show the message to user.

```
handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {

 let errorMessage = '';
 if(err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
   errorMessage = err.error.message 
 } else {
   errorMessage = err.error;
 }
 return throwError(errorMessage);
}
```

But I found out that these to different methods return types would not get mapped very well to the Angular.

If I use `BadRequest("Error1")` my message would appear in

`err.error.Message`

If I used the

`ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Error2"));` it would appear in

`err.error`

I was wondering if it was possible to use both response types in my backend and get similar response to handle in the SPA.

I guess I could always use the `ResponseMessage` version to know that the error wold be understood everywhere in the SPA but I cant make sure someone else on the team wont use the `BadRequest` method.

Comment: You could try making your own custom `IHttpActionResult` and map it the way you want. Here's what I found on my bookmark for custom `IHttpActionResult` http://www.sunilrav.com/post/ASPNET-Web-Api-custom-IHttpActionResult-for-HTTP-Forbidden